# C language : How to store data of structure in one line?

Tags: c, structure

I have a structure that stores coordinates (x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>).

```
typedef struct _FCOORD{
    float X;
    float Y;
}FCOORD,*PFCOORD;
```

Now I define a variable named point and store some data

```
FCOORD point;
point.X=20.00f;
point.Y=20.00f;
```

I want to just load data like this:

```
point={20.00f,20.00f};
```

I am coding in C language using gcc compiler

```
C:\My_Assets\MinGW\bin>gcc --version
gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I get this error when compiling

```
gcc -c ./src/main.c -I"F:\Codes\Windows\Application\include"
In file included from ./src/main.c:13:0:
./src/threads.c: In function 'WorkerThread':
./src/threads.c:66:19: error: expected expression before '{' token
     R1_data.start={10,10};
                   ^
```

**EDIT**: Please mention similar case for structure pointer too i.e PFCOORD. Thank you.

Comment: If it's at the declaration point, you can use an initializer:  `FCOORD point = {20.00f,20.00f};`

Comment: Here's a rule of thumb: whenever you get the urge to "I must do it in one line", you are doing it wrong. What you rather should be considering is: "I must do this in the most readable way possible". There is nothing wrong with your initial code. Sure it can also be written in a single line using compound literals, but that's not really making things any better or worse in this case.

Comment: However, hiding a pointer behind a typedef like your `PFCOORD` is horrible practice and very likely the reason why your program crashed when you tried the proposed answers. Never hide pointers behind typedef - it will just confuse everyone reading the code including yourself.

Comment: Completely opinion, but one ight argue that if a change makes code _neither better nor worse_ from a readability/comprehension standpoint, but expresses it more concisely, that does make the program _better_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) for such an assignment:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct FCOORD {
    float X;
    float Y;
} FCOORD;

int main()
{
    FCOORD point;
    point.X = 20.00f;
    point.Y = 20.00f;

    point = (FCOORD){ 42.00f, 3.1415927f }; // The RHS here is a compound literal

    printf("%f %f\n", point.X, point.Y);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that, as mentioned on the linked cppreference page, although they *look* a lot like casts, compound literals are *not* casts and behave very differently.

Also note that I removed the leading underscore from your `_FCOORD` type name; identifiers with leading underscores followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for use by the implementation.

You can also add designated initializers to the assignment shown in the code above; this may be useful if you want to assign the elements "out of order", or if there are other structure members that you don't want to explicitly assign<sup>1</sup>. Using these, the line would be like this:

```c
    point = (FCOORD){ .Y = 3.1415927f, .X = 42.00f };
```

---

<sup>1</sup> But, be careful in the latter case (where you have members that are not explicitly set in the compound literal): These will *not* keep their 'original' values but will, instead, be default initialized.

Comment: Well I tried this and it was ok because compiler did not show any errors. However the data was not set and after sometime the program crashed and showed this error.
./bin/main.exe 
make: *** [run] Error -1073741819

Comment: Ok well its running again thank you. But please can you show me similar example for pointer structure PFCOORD too.

Comment: @Sammy1410  Hmm. Not completely sure what you mean. As it happens, you *can* take the address of a compound literal but that would likely lead to a mess at some point (the created struct would likely go out of scope). Alternatively, you can assign the compound literal to the **dereferenced** pointer. So, if `pfc` is a pointer to an `FCOORD` struct, do `*pfc = (FCOORD){ 1.1f, 2.2f };` (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this when declaring and initializing at the same time.

```
typedef struct A { int b; int c; } At;

int main(void) {
  At a = {.b=42, .c=27};

  return 0;
}
```

But you cannot use this after declaration. This will not compile.

```
typedef struct A { int b; int c; } At;

int main(void) {
  At a;
  a = {.b=42, .c=27};

  return 0;
}
```

Outside of initialization, you can assign a compound literal. Note that this is a C99 feature, and you may have problems with this if using an older compiler. If so, *get a new compiler*.

```
typedef struct A { int b; int c; } At;

int main(void) {
  At a;
  a = (At){.b=42, .c=27};

  return 0;
}
```